# Адрес памяти для каждого байта отдельный?

Tags: c++, память

У каждого байта есть свой адрес?

Если создать переменную int (у меня весит 4 байта). Адрес памяти один для 4 байт, или для каждого байта отдельный адрес?

```
int x = 1;
```

например переменная `x` весит 4 байта, я могу как-то обращаться к каждому байту отдельно?

в памяти это выглядит так?

```
            0xFF // address
00000000000000000000000000000001 // 32bit
```

или так?

```
  0x1 
00000000 // 8bit
  0x2
00000000
  0x3
00000000
  0x4
00000001
```

Comment: Память определяют адрес и размер. 4-байтовая переменная имеет некий адрес N и размер 4 байта. Её первый байт имеет тот же адрес и размер 1. Её второй байт имеет адрес N+1 и размер 1... и так далее. *У каждого байта есть свой адрес?* На самом деле наоборот - каждый адрес содержит байт. Но поскольку при фиксированном в байт размере это симметричное условие, то ответ может быть и "да".

Comment: А про какой язык речь не написали. Хотя в общем случае это не важно, но всё-таки. Обращаться к каждому байту можно, но приведя тип к однобайтовому предварительно. Насколько я помню C-образные языки при адресной арифметике учитывают тип. Т.е. если взять адрес 4-байтовой переменной и прибавить 1, то прибавится на самом деле 4, и это логично при работе с массивами и т.п., вы ведь наверняка хотите получить адрес следующего элемента массива, когда прибавляете к адресу 1 - думает за вас компилятор.

Comment: У каждого байта свой адрес, но с заданного адреса можно прочесть несколько байт (в случае int 4 байта)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В памяти для 32-битного `int` это выглядит так:

```
0x1233  0x1232  0x1231  0x1230
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

если это little-endian, а если big-endian, то

```
0x1230  0x1231  0x1232  0x1233
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

Т.е. это *единое целое* из 4 байтов, но в принципе вы можете обратиться (адресовать) к каждому байту отдельно. Но единое число типа `int` занимает 4 байта и имеет адрес (в приведенном случае) 0x1230.

Грубо говоря, вы можете обратиться к каждому ученику в классе (но не отдельно к его, скажем, желудку :)), но для какого-то школьного мероприятия класс — единое целое со старостой класса во главе, по которому можно адресовать весь класс :)

Comment: как можно обратится например к 2 байту?

Comment: `int p;  unsigned char& second_byte = *((unsigned char*)&p+1);` - если ко второму в смысле, что в числе байты с первого по четвертый.

Comment: можно обратиться и к желудку, если его достать из ученика - аналогии в программировании зло)

Comment: "укш Для этого потребуется хирургическая операция, т.е. применение битовых операций для получения отдельного бита.

Comment: я правильно понял?      `typedef unsigned char UBYTE;

 uint32_t x(1); UBYTE* const ptr = reinterpret_cast<UBYTE*>(&x);
        std::cout << ptr[0];`  Если у меня последовательность байтов была бы  big-endian, то вывело бы 0, а если little-endian, то 1

Comment: Ну да, все так.

Answer (score 8):

В общем случае наличие переменной отнюдь не означает выделенную память. Переменная может быть размещена компилятором в регистре, она может быть размещена по одному адресу с другой переменной (например, если их области жизни не пересекаются), код может быть преобразован так, что ваша переменная вовсе исчезнет.

Мой [любимый пример](https://godbolt.org/z/YK9cnYfe7): вот такой код

```cpp
unsigned int sum(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int acc = 0; 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        acc += i;
    return acc;
}
```

оптимизирующий компилятор преобразует в такой ассемблер:

```assembler
sum(unsigned int):
        mov     ecx, edi
        lea     eax, [rdi - 1]
        imul    rax, rcx
        shr     rax
        add     eax, edi
        ret
```

(который можно примерно перевести назад на C++ как `return num * (num - 1) / 2 + num`).

Сколько байт весит переменная `i` исходного кода? Вопрос некорректен.

---

Ещё один [любопытный пример](https://godbolt.org/z/h9M6cncq5): код

```cpp
class adder
{
    int a, b;
public:
    adder(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    int get() { return a + b; }
};

int add0(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int add1(int x, int y)
{
    adder w(x, y);
    return w.get();
}

int add2(int x, int y)
{
    adder* pw = new adder(x, y);
    int result = pw->get();
    delete pw;
    return result;
}

int add3(int x, int y)
{
    adder* pw = new adder(x, y);
    try
    {
        int result = pw->get();
        delete pw;
        return result;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        delete pw;
        throw;
    }
}

int add4(int x, int y)
{
    std::unique_ptr<adder> pw { new adder(x, y) };
    return pw->get();
}
```

скомпилровался в обычное

```assembler
add0(int, int):
        lea     eax, [rdi + rsi]
        ret
add1(int, int):
        lea     eax, [rdi + rsi]
        ret
add2(int, int):
        lea     eax, [rdi + rsi]
        ret
add3(int, int):
        lea     eax, [rdi + rsi]
        ret
add4(int, int):
        lea     eax, [rdi + rsi]
        ret
```

то есть все пять функций компилируются в аналог `return x + y;`. Какой адрес объекта `adder`? Где он расположен, в стеке или в куче? Вопрос некорректен.

Компилятор обязан следовать *семантике* вашего кода: если код по сути считает сумму чисел, то после компиляции должна получиться сумма чисел. Компилятор не обязан следовать *синтаксису* вашего кода: если для сложения вы используете дополнительный класс, компилятор вовсе не обязан делать то же самое. Поэтому компилятор имеет право под капотом менять код, убирать и добавлять переменные, менять алгоритм с квадратичного на линейный и наоборот, убирать аллокации, всё что угодно. Понятия исходного кода (переменные, функции, классы, команды) вовсе не обязаны иметь соответствие в компиляте.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140593/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------).

Answer (score 4):

Не пойму почему в ответах нет прямого ответа на вопрос: как разбить int на байты?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   int i = 1;
   unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*) &i;
   
   printf("%X %X %X %X\n", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]);

   return(0);
}
```

Один из вариантов.

Comment: Мой ответ отвечает на вопрос «как выглядит переменная в памяти». И ответ на это — никакой гарантии нет, вопрос некорректен.

Comment: это как с фотонами - начинаешь её смотреть и она появляется - тк она не убирается оптимизацией теперь

Comment: Это да. А ещё дзен-буддисты спрашивали, есть ли звук от падающего дерева в пустом лесу (то есть если никто не слушает).